# How To check data-base Table to find whether the value is already there?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new to android and sqlLite,
I want to prepare code for checking whether the given value in the EditText is already 
there in the database table or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
boolean editTextValue= false;
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        String recorded_editTextValue=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("editTextValue"));
        if(recorded_editTextValue.equals(new_recorded_editTextValue)){ 
            editTextValue= true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!editTextValue)
        // add new_record_editTextValue to database
```

here:  **new_recorded_editTextValue** is new insert value

**recorded_editTextValue** is existing value of db

Comment: @CL. updated my answer with cursor. Let me know if there any problem with my code..

Comment: Well, loading all records and doing the comparison in your own code is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Then what is the sufficient way?

Answer (score -1):

Use following function it will return true if database table contains editext value other vise it will return false

// Please change TableName to your database table in which you want to check value and columnname to your table column in which you are checking

```
private boolean checkValueFromDatabaseTable() {
        DatabaseHelper dbhelp = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelp.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from TableName where columnname ='" + edittext.getText().toString() + "'", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) 
                    {

            //Means you have matching value in table so return true
                        return true;

        }
                    else
                    {
                       return false;
                    }
        db.close();
        db.releaseReference();
        dbhelp.close();
    }
```

Comment: This will blow up when the edittext contains a quote.

Comment: @CL i have given him the solution validation and other part he has to manage because he is not given us the complete requirement

Answer (score -1):

```
    To check the value from database use this code:

    public boolean isFileExist(String edittextValue){
                String q="Select column_name from table_name WHERE column_name='"+edittextValue+"'";
                Cursor cur=sdb.rawQuery(q, null);
                boolean isExist=false;
                while(cur.moveToNext()){
                    isExist=true;
                }
                cur.close();
                return isExist;
            }

Just pass your edit text value in argument of this method
If it returns true then value exist or returns false means value does not exist
```

Comment: This will blow up when the edittext contains a quote.

Comment: Please explain why are you passing quote?

Comment: Why me? Any user can type a quote into the edit box.

Comment: Sorry this method is only for checking value is present in the database or not. I think you have to check edit text validation first.

Comment: What validation? A quote is a valid input.